# Create database in External Storage

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

I know already how create Sqlite database. The point is the database file is created only in Internal Storage (/data/{package name})

Is there a way to directly create Sqlite database right on External Storage?

Comment: AFAIK, `openOrCreateDatabase()` on `SQLiteDatabase` accepts a fully-qualified path, as of API Level 8 or so. Bear in mind that external storage is not always available (though on modern devices it usually is available). If external storage were to become unavailable in the middle of a transaction, you may get database corruption as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your database like so:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private yourPath = "/mnt/sdcard/";

private SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(yourPath + "sudoku.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

**Edit** Your methods:

```
private static Cursor query(String query) {
    if (query != null) {
        openDB();

        while (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
            // db in use, keep looping
        }

        Log.d("Query", query);

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static void openDB() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(yourPath + "sudoku.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing I'm trying to figure out is: do I need I helper class? I usually create a instance of Sqlite database referring to Sqlite helper class

Comment: @tdmsoares  No you don't need it.  Edited my answer above to show the methods you can use.

Answer (score 0):

After Android 11 you must use somewhat like this

```
public static final String DATABASE_PATH=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME="database_name.db";


SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME,null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```